# Why does zero have a sign in the following example?

Tags: javascript

Has somebody a clue why zero is signed while performing this operation on JavaScript?

```
null/-Infinity = -0
null/Infinity = 0
```

Comment: There's a fairly comprehensive discussion about this [here](http://css.dzone.com/articles/javascripts-two-zeros)

Comment: Your beef is properly with [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), not with JavaScript, in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - The sign of the result is positive if both operands have the same
>     sign, negative if the operands have different signs.
> - Division of a finite value by an infinity results in zero. The sign is
>     determined by the rule already stated above.

http://es5.github.io/#x11.5.2

PS: `null` is converted to `+0` (see http://es5.github.io/#x9.3) before applying `/` operator (as per http://es5.github.io/#x11.5)

Comment: Not to say I care that much, but why `-1`? :-S

Comment: @Fabrício Matté: nope, it was downvoted. Now it's not

Comment: Ohh, -1 in terms of downvote, I thought you were talking about another mathematical problem hah.